# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'goLineEnd' of undefined - codemirror erors

Tags: javascript, editor, codemirror

The last time I started writing my code editor, I use a code mirror for my project. I want to add a duplicate current line, but something still goes wrong.
My code:

```js
var current_cursor = CodeMirror.doc.getCursor();
var line_content = CodeMirror.doc.getLine(current_cursor.line);
CodeMirror.commands.goLineEnd(CodeMirror);
CodeMirror.commands.newlineAndIndent(CodeMirror);
CodeMirror.doc.replaceSelection(line_content);
CodeMirror.doc.setCursor(current_cursor.line + 1, current_cursor.ch);
```

I think that the same name of variable CodeMirror and CodeMirror object can cause this error:

```js
CodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.querySelector('.editor'), {
  extraKeys: { 'Ctrl-D': duplicate_line },
});
```

Have you got any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Based on the error message, `CodeMirror.commands` isn't an object. Double-check the documentation for CodeMirror and make sure that a) `commands` is definitely the name of the object, and b) the documentation you're following is for the version of CodeMirror you're using.

Comment: Yes, I checked this at https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#commands , but I think the problem is in CodeMirror word

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. I do not know why my code was not working. For everybody that has got the same problem:

```
async function duplicate_line()
{
    var current_cursor = CodeMirror.doc.getCursor();
    var line_content = CodeMirror.doc.getLine(current_cursor.line);
    CodeMirror.execCommand('goLineEnd');
    CodeMirror.execCommand('newlineAndIndent');
    CodeMirror.doc.replaceSelection(line_content);
    CodeMirror.doc.setCursor(current_cursor.line + 1, current_cursor.ch);
}
```